# Can we create a proxy like system for Local storage (Disk) of IO stream from any program?

Tags: c#, windows, proxy, stream, byte

1st of all I am not trying to make anything related to web or networking,
I learn making proxy servers and all in networking using C#

but now I wanted to make proxy like system for my system where any application trying to read/write file from local storage must get the data from my local proxy like system.

My objective to do this is,
I have a game which loads all it's files from the local files, but those files are not safe and anyone can edit it
So I wanted to encrypt those game files and when the game loads those files, It will be decrypted and then loaded to the game so that no one will get the decrypted data

Kinda same like Proxy do, as a man in middle
data goes through it so we can control what data to send where

I want kinda same system in local storage so that when the game reads it's files, the game files data will go though my application and it will be decrypted and then game will load it

Comment: You cannot hope to secure a system where an attacker has physical access to it. It's not clear what sort of security you hope to gain from encrypting your game data over, say, signing it and verifying the signature. Anyway, if you want to keep chasing the proxy idea, you'll have to write a file system filter driver. You cannot use C# for that.

Comment: In case this wasn't explicit enough: Verifying a digital signature requires that the public key is available to the client machine. Decrypting data requires that you hand out the **private** key. Definitely not what you want.